# ArgoCD and Vault Integration Issue: Unresolved Error in Admin Interface

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, hashicorp-vault, argocd

I'm deploying this 'classic' infrastructure using Terraform
https://github.com/openfun/kubic

I've been trying to understand why ArgoCD is not working with Vault for the second day already. I followed all the instructions. On the last step, I set up the infrastructure using bin/terraform-apply.sh scaleway. I successfully obtained the load balancer's IP and linked it to the domains. Next, I followed the Vault setup instructions. I generated cluster-keys.json and was able to access the Vault admin interface using the root_token from this file. However, I still see an error on the ArgoCD admin page:

> rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Manifest generation error (cached): plugin sidecar
> failed. error generating manifests in cmp: rpc error: code = Unknown
> desc = error generating manifests: sh -c "helm template
> $ARGOCD_APP_NAME -n $ARGOCD_APP_NAMESPACE ${ARGOCD_ENV_HELM_ARGS}
> --include-crds . |\nargocd-vault-plugin generate - -s ${ARGOCD_ENV_AVP_SECRET}\n" failed exit status 1: Error: Error making
> API request. URL: PUT
> https://vault-st.my_site.io/v1/auth/kubernetes/login Code: 403.
> Errors: * service account name not authorized Usage:
> argocd-vault-plugin generate [flags] Flags: -c, --config-path string
> path to a file containing Vault configuration (YAML, JSON, envfile) to
> use -h, --help help for generate -s, --secret-name string name of a
> Kubernetes Secret in the argocd namespace containing Vault
> configuration data in the argocd namespace of your ArgoCD host (Only
> available when used in ArgoCD). The namespace can be overridden by
> using the format : --verbose-sensitive-output enable verbose mode for
> detailed info to help with debugging. Includes sensitive data
> (credentials), logged to stderr

I tried reinstalling ArgoCD with Vault already configured (commented out the contents of argocd.tf, did a plan and apply, and then uncommented and did a plan and apply), but it didn't help. I keep seeing this error. What am I doing wrong? Are there any additional steps that may be required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply didn't complete the last step of the vault setup, which is done through Terraform. I was thrown off by the note that said 'This part is not mandatory.', and I just skipped it. However, it's a crucial step, as without it, no application in ArgoCD will work